# Adobe flex : want DropDownList custom renderer to display values in hex AND display the chosen value in hex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flash-builder

I have some data that I want stored in decimal, but displayed in hex in an s:DropDownList.  I have developed the custom renderer and the drop down list displays the numbers in hex fine, BUT when the number is selected it is displayed in decimal.  I want the number to be stored as decimal, but always displayed in hex, both in the dropdown and when chosen.  How can I do this?

The custom renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"        
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:Label text="{makeLabel(data)}"/>

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function makeLabel(data:Object):String {
            var x:int = data as int;
            var ret:String = x.toString(16);
            if (ret.length < 2) {
                ret = '0' + ret;
            }
            return ret.toUpperCase() + 'H';
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Test stub:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        public var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([9, 10, 11, 12]);
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:DropDownList x="72" y="43" dataProvider="{dp}" itemRenderer="HexListRenderer"/>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DropDownList.labelFunction

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        public var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([9, 10, 11, 12]);

        public function makeLabel(data:Object):String {
            var x:int = data as int;
            var ret:String = x.toString(16);
            if (ret.length < 2) {
                ret = '0' + ret;
            }
            return ret.toUpperCase() + 'H';
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:DropDownList x="72" y="43" labelFunction="makeLabel" dataProvider="{dp}" itemRenderer="HexListRenderer"/>

</s:Application>
```